# Magento 2 Commerce : Add to cart not working for gift card product

Tags: gift-card, magento-2-commerce

I am trying to add  giftcard product to cart but its not working
it shows "Please specify a delivery date." error on frontend.

```
Magento ver. 2.4.1 Commerce
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have some customizations in there. There is no delivery date info on products in the default Magento install. I also tried your flow of adding a giftcard product to cart and no errors occurred on the M2.4.1 with sample data.

My suggestion is to enable a debugger and see what's going on and also check which are the properties set on the product in admin area (attribute set details, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
it was due a condition in module.

Comment: you're welcome ;)

Comment: I have email settings configured to receive emails, i have added recipient email in giftcard product & ordered the product.

but the email did not sent to recipient email.
I am not sure magento has behaviour to send email to recipient in giftcard product.

Can you share your thoughts on this ?

Comment: I think your configuration was left to generate the gift card code when the order is invoiced and not when it was created. go to **admin -> stores -> configuration -> sales -> gift cards -> Generate Gift Card Account when Orders Item** and change from *Invoiced* to ***Ordered*** . More details here https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-gift-card-account-configuration.html#step-2-complete-the-general-settings

Comment: Hi @devhs receiver will receive email with Gift card code when you create invoice. If you want to send email when order created you need to change setting from admin.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response.